# Create SecretStore vault without a password

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get more familiar with using the somewhat new PowerShell module `Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement`, using the `Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore` vault extension module.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to register the SecretStore without a password from the beginning. AKA, you never have to provide a password at all.

Here's what I'm trying:

Install the modules:

```powershell
Install-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement, Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore
```

Register a new SecretVault using the SecretStore module as the default:

```powershell
Register-SecretVault -Name SecretStore -ModuleName Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore -DefaultVault
```

Now here is where I run into issues...

If I try this:

```powershell
Set-SecretStoreConfiguration -Interaction None -Authentication None
```

I end up with this:

```plaintext
PS C:\> Set-SecretStoreConfiguration -Interaction None -Authentication None

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Changes local store configuration" on target "SecretStore module local store".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
Vault Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore requires a password.
Enter password:
****
A password is no longer required for the local store configuration.
To complete the change please provide the current password.
Enter password:
****
PS C:\>
```

I can't tell if I'm doing something wrong, or if I should submit this as a bug? It doesn't make sense for it to ask me for a password if I say it doesn't need one, and then ask me to provide the same password to remove it.

If it's not a bug, then the only thing I can think of is that it's still using the password behind the scenes for the encryption/decryption process, and the setting `Authentication` is more about usage of the vault, but the password itself is still used for encryption/decryption.

---

I also tried passing in default registration parameters to `Register-SecretVault` like this:

```plaintext
-VaultParameters @{Authentication='None'; Interaction='None'}
```

And it still required a password, in fact, it didn't even apply the settings after registration, it seems to ignore them completely:

```plaintext
PS C:\> Register-SecretVault -ModuleName Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore -Name SecretStore -VaultParameters @{Authentication='None'; Interaction='None'} -DefaultVault
PS C:\> Set-Secret -Name Testing -Secret 'Testing123'
Creating a new SecretStore vault. A password is required by the current store configuration.
Enter password:
****
Enter password again for verification:
****
PS C:\> Get-SecretStoreConfiguration

      Scope Authentication PasswordTimeout Interaction
      ----- -------------- --------------- -----------
CurrentUser       Password             900      Prompt

PS C:\>
```

Answer (score 5):

Below are the complete steps for adding/retrieving keys from SecretVault **without** prompting for a password.

#### Install the modules:

`$> Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement, Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore -Repository PSGallery`

#### Register the vault

`$> Register-SecretVault -Name your-datastore -ModuleName Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore -DefaultVault`

#### Check 'your-datastore' vault

`$> Get-SecretVault`

#### Create a master password to access your 'your-datastore' Vault

`$> Get-SecretStoreConfiguration`

#### Change the configuration of the store (this will disable the password prompt)

`$> Set-SecretStoreConfiguration -Authentication None -Interaction None`

#### Create a secret

`$> Set-Secret -Vault your-datastore -Name your-secret -Secret "your-secret-string"`

#### Get the secret value

`$> Get-Secret -Vault your-datastore -Name your-secret -AsPlainText`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$null` for setting `None` value to your vault parameters.
For example:

```
# To register the vault with Interaction & Authentication values to None
Register-SecretVault -Name test-secret-store -VaultParameters @{Authentication=$null; Interaction=$null} -ModuleName Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore

# Create a secret
Set-Secret -Name test-secret -Secret "my secret password" -Vault test-secret-store

# Get the secret value
Get-Secret -Name test-secret -AsPlainText -Vault test-secret-store
```

To get more information about $null you can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null?view=powershell-7.2) article.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work anymore. 'Set-Secret' triggers "Creating a new  [your-vault] vault. A password is required by the current store configuration." message. I haven't figured workaround yet, if anyone did, please share